# Questions on configuring the YAML file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, api-gateway

I'm trying to set up a yaml file for the Gateway API to post to a cloud function, but I don't know how to do that, I searched the internet and found some examples but when I created the gateway with the settings of my YAML file I get the following error:

[image]

I know the cause of the error is probably a YAML file indentation error, but I'm not able to resolve it.

My YAML file is configured as follows:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: gateway-homologation gateway for homologation of the project cycle
  description: "Send a deal object for the data to be treated"
  version: "1.0.0"
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /dispatcher:
    post:
      x-google-backend: 
        address: https://url
      description: "Jailson esteve aqui =)"
      operationId: "dispatcher"
      parameters:
        type: object
        properties: 
          request_type:
            type: string
          deal:
            name:
              type: string

      responses:
        200:
          description: "#OK"
          schema:
            type: string
        400:
          description: "#OPS"
```

Another question is how can I configure what my gateway will send to my cloud function?

Comment: The error message is quite clear that at `/paths/~1dispatcher/post/parameters`, an array is expected but an object is given. This is not a YAML error, but a schema error – you have to give the structure defined by the schema. Making the value of `parameters` an array will overcome that error, but I do not know enough about Swagger to be confident that this is the only error in your code.

Comment: @flyx, I understood what you said but I'm not able to do this. How would I turn the object into an array in practice?

Comment: [the docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/) have some examples; `-` starts a sequence item; sequence items make up a YAML sequence and in JavaScript context will be loaded as an array.

Comment: @flyx , your comments are very helpful. Could you please post them as an Answer instead of a comment for the Community's benefit?

Comment: @NestorDanielOrtegaPerez I only post comments because an answer should show how to make the given data valid, which my comments don't. The link I posted states that parameters do not have `properties` so the input will still be invalid after this fix and I have no idea what to do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" -The error message is quite clear that at /paths/~1dispatcher/post/parameters, an array is expected but an object is given. This is not a YAML error, but a schema error – you have to give the structure defined by the schema. Making the value of parameters an array will overcome that error, but I do not know enough about Swagger to be confident that this is the only error in your code.

-I understood what you said but I'm not able to do this. How would I turn the object into an array in practice?

- The docs [Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/%22) have some examples; - starts a sequence item; sequence items make up a YAML sequence and in JavaScript context will be loaded as an array.

@flyx